# Sort ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

```
class Student { 
    int rollno; 
    String name, address; 

    // Constructor 
    public Student(int rollno, String name, String address) { 
        this.rollno = rollno; 
        this.name = name; 
        this.address = address; 
    } 

    // Used to print student details in main() 
    public String toString() { 
        return this.rollno + " " + this.name + 
                           " " + this.address; 
    } 
} 

class tools {
    class Sortbyroll implements Comparator<Student>{ 
        // Used for sorting in ascending order of 
        // roll number 
        public int compare(Student a, Student b) { 
            return a.rollno - b.rollno; 
        } 
    }
    public ArrayList<Student> sort(ArrayList<Student> arr){
        Collections.sort(arr, new Sortbyroll());
        return arr;
    }
}

class Main 
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) { 

        ArrayList<Student> ar = new ArrayList<Student>(); 
        ar.add(new Student(111, "bbbb", "london")); 
        ar.add(new Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc")); 
        ar.add(new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur")); 

        System.out.println("Unsorted"); 
        for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++) 
            System.out.println(ar.get(i)); 

        ar = tools.sort(ar);

        System.out.println("\nSorted by rollno"); 
        for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++) 
            System.out.println(ar.get(i)); 
    } 
}
```

I can sort it if i put the Sortbyroll outside the tools
But i can only submit the student.java file and the tool.java file
so basically i have to do everything inside student class and tool class
and main function cannot be edited...

if i put the sort function static
it said "error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"
what should i do ...

Comment: You need to make both `sort` method and `Sortbyroll` class **`static`**.

Comment: *FYI:* Don't do `a.rollno - b.rollno` as that can fail because of numeric overflow. Use [`Integer.compare(a.rollno, b.rollno)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use compareTo method inside of Student class. change your student model:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student>{ 
int rollno; 
String name, address; 

// Constructor 
public Student(int rollno, String name, String address) { 
    this.rollno = rollno; 
    this.name = name; 
    this.address = address; 
} 

// Used to print student details in main() 
public String toString() { 
    return this.rollno + " " + this.name + 
                       " " + this.address; 
} 

 public int compareTo(Student model) {
    return model.rollno.compareTo(rollno);
}
}
```

and in main use `Collections.sort(response);` to sort Array List

Answer (score -1):

Replace your Tools class with the following code.

```
    class tools {
    static public ArrayList<Student> sort(ArrayList<Student> arr){
        Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Object s1, Object s2) {
                return Integer.compare(((Student)s1).rollno, ((Student)s2).rollno);
            }

        });
        return arr;
    }
}
```